# How to get an XML file for an sql query result

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to build a report using BI publisher for which i need xml file for a query result am using SQL developer for executing my queries.

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle provides a lot of syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb13gen.htm) for writing out XML formatted content from database columns.

You might want to explore some of that.

It will generate one xml document per row of your query.

If that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Google "oracle bi publisher xml output" =>

http://cali97.blogspot.com/2008/01/bi-publisher-xml-publisher-can-produce.html

'Hope that helps...